# how to call class method without writing class name in command line

Tags: python

Here is the code, its just a simple example:

```
class func(object):

    def cacul(self, a, b):
        return a+b

    def run_cacul(self, a, b):
        return self.cacul(a, b)
```

I'm trying to call the class method `run_cacul()` through import this module in command line. The module name is 'foo.py'

```
import foo

foo.func().run_cacul(2,3)
```

It's too long!! I don't want to write the class name, just like python's system module `random.py`, it omits the class name `Random()`

```
import random

random.randint(12,23)
```

The code maybe wrong, but I just want to know the method. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: random isnt a class, its a module. If you want similar functionality, move cacul and run_cacul out of the func class if it doesnt need to be there.

Comment: Then make it a function, not a class method.

Comment: foo is not a class, either. what if I dont want to make it a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have defined the methods inside class then without creating object or without referencing the class, its impossible to invoke the method.

As for random example `randint` is function reference

```
_inst = Random()
randint = _inst.randint
```

object of Random is created and `randint` function reference is stored in `randint`.
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py#L775
Object creation is hidden from client (us).

Along the similar lines you can do same: **foo.py**

```
class func(object):

    def cacul(self, a, b):
        return a+b

    def run_cacul(self, a, b):
        return self.cacul(a, b)

obj = func()
run_cacul = obj.run_cacul
```

then you can do like

```
from foo import ran_cacul
ran_cacul(4,5)
```

Comment: it is, Thank you, thats very useful!